# Update errno in signal handler

Tags: c, linux, signals

The following code is from book The Linux Programming Interface, it is supposed to resolve that using errno makes a function non-reentrant which is required for signal handler.

```
void
handler(int sig)
{
    int savedErrno;

    savedErrno = errno;

    /* Now we can execute a function that might modify errno */

    errno = savedErrno;
}
```

But I do not think it is safe practice. If this function serves as handler for several signals, or if SA_NODEFER is set which makes this function interruptible by itself, then global variable errno still makes this function non-reentrant. Is my understanding right?

Comment: "then global variable errno"?  What makes you think `errno` is just a simple "global variable"?  [It's not](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p2).

Comment: When multithreading was introduced (e.g. `pthreads`), `errno` was changed from (e.g.) `extern int errno;` into `extern int *__errno_location(void); #define errno (*__errno_location())`. Thus, `errno` is part of thread local storage. And, other threads do _not_ affect it. And, in the signal handler usage here, it _is_ reentrant (regardless of the true definition of `errno`) because it _is_ saved/restored in the signal handler.